# Is the USD amount the same for both sender and receiver?

Tags: transactions, exchange-rate, price-volatility

I sent .004 bitcoin to someone. In USD the amount was $223. The receiving party said they received only USD $212. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin's exchange rate is volatile, so 0.004 BTC can be worth $223 at one time and $212 not much later. If you're agreeing to pay someone (or be paid) in bitcoin, be sure to agree on an amount *denominated* in bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

The Bitcoin currency was designed as a separate currency in its own right, it was not designed as a means of sending other currencies.

The Euro currency was not designed for sending US dollars either. If you exchange $223 into Euros, send those Euros to someone else and they exchange the received Euros into US dollars, the amount of US dollars they receive is almost always going to be different from the amount originally used to purchase Euros. Typically when the recipient uses a currency exchange to exchange the Euros for US dollars, a different exchange rate applies (the buying, selling "spread"), so they might only get $212.

Every time you exchange one currency for another you are almost certainly going to pay a fee for that service.